# How can I work out the length of the sides of an Equilateral triangle that exists in a circle?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles, triangles

I'm making a game and need a bit of mathematics help.

If I have a circle with a radius of $x$ and there is an equilateral triangle in the center made up of $3$ equal chords. How can I work out the length of the sides of the triangle?

I actually want to split the equilateral triangle into $3$ different isosceles triangles(making a straight line from the center to the corner of the equilateral triangle). The $2$ equal sides are obviously $x$ in length. But the last side's length eludes me.

I'd prefer not to use trig. Computers generally don't like any form of roots. But I can probably find a way to optimize it if that's my only solution.

Thanks in advance.

[Triangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58SCb.jpg) I added this Image for clarity. I need the value y.

Comment: Not sure this is clear.  The triangle is inscribed in the circle?  If so, then the Law of Cosines gets you the result ($\sqrt 3 r$).  Or did you mean something else?

Comment: Please provide a picture to be clear.

Comment: Hint: notable angles (trig is a must.)

Comment: @Rócherz, I wouldn't be surprised if there is a solution that does not use trig...

Comment: I added an image for clarity. :)

Comment: @Rócherz what's a notable angle? Also could I not perhaps use the golden ratio here? I don't fully understand the golden ratio.

Comment: After reading [This](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Equilateral_triangle) I realized that @lulu was correct. If lulu or anyone else adds this with a more detailed explanation, I'll mark it as the answer :) I won't answer myself as I don't fully understand the solution and would like someone who understands it better to answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No trig is needed for the answer, though the law of Cosines gives a direct approach.

To do it via basic geometry, draw a radius out to one of the vertices.  By Symmetry it bisects the angle there.  Dropping the perpendicular out to a side of the equilateral triangle, gives us a $30-60-90$ right triangle with hypotenuse $x$, the radius of the circle.  Of course, the side opposite the $60$ degree angle has length $\frac {\sqrt 3}2\,x$ from which it follows that the length of one side of the equilateral triangle is $$\boxed {\sqrt 3\,x}$$

Comment: Thanks! Lulu, Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This is what I used to do before I came to know about trigonometry.
[image: enter image description here.]
Let $BD$ be the median. 
Medians of an equilateral triangle pass through the circumcenter. So circumcenter is the centroid of triangle. Centroid divide median in $\frac21$. So $\frac{BO}{OD}=\frac21 \implies BD=\frac{3x}{2}$. $BD$ is also the altitude of the triangle. Now altitude of an equilateral triangle of side $a$ is equal to $\frac{a\sqrt3}{2}$. $$\frac{a\sqrt3}{2}=\frac{3x}{2}\\
a=\frac{3x}{\sqrt3}=\sqrt3x$$